# How to scrape single linkedin post with PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape posts from linkedin with PHP.

Consider this URL: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/linkedin_simple-reminder-believe-in-yourself-activity-6668872904807092224-pMVk

I'm trying to get the content of this post (this is a regular feed post written by a user). Meaning i should get this as a result: 'Simple reminder: Believe in yourself.'

Has anyone done this? I've tried to extract the information with file_get_contents() and then doing an $xpath->query("//*[@id='ember86']"); as well as other approaches but i either get null or [unable to retrieve full text content]

Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: There's a good chance you'll wind up hitting a captcha if you do this for a while.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think this case will happen to often. It's not an automated scraping and i don't think there will be too much linkedin scraping anyways

Comment: I wouldn't underestimate LinkedIn's desire to prevent scraping. They (thankfully) failed to make it a crime (https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/10/20859399/linkedin-hiq-data-scraping-cfaa-lawsuit-ninth-circuit-ruling) but they're pretty aggressive about preventing automated access via technological means where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to extract what you need with Regular Expression. E.g:

```
<?php 
$page=@file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com/posts/linkedin_simple-reminder-believe-in-yourself-activity-6668872904807092224-pMVk");
if($page){
    preg_match_all("/<p class=\"share-update-card__update-text public-post__update-text\">([^<]+)<\/p>/",$page,$matches);
    if(isset($matches[1][0])){
        echo $matches[1][0];
    }else{
        echo "No match found!";
    }
}else{
    echo "failed to load page";
}
?>
```

**Update:**

```
<?php 
$page=@file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com/posts/dineshkarna_the-biology-of-courage-what-is-that-ugcPost-6668335979088216064-nQwk/");
if($page){
    $data=array();

    preg_match_all("/<p class=\"share-update-card__update-text public-post__update-text\">([^<]+)<\/p>/",$page,$title_matches);
    if(isset($title_matches[1][0])){
        $data["title"]=$title_matches[1][0];
    }else{
        $data["title"]=null;
    }

    preg_match_all("/<video class=\"share-native-video__node video-js\"data-sources=\"(\[[^\]]*\])\"data-poster-url=\"([^\"]*)\".*><\/video>/",$page,$video_matches);
    if(isset($video_matches[1][0])){
        $data["videos"]=json_decode(html_entity_decode($video_matches[1][0]),true);
        var_dump($data["videos"]); 
        exit;
    }else{
        $data["videos"]=null;
    }

    var_dump($data);
    exit;
}else{
    echo "failed to load page";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed i get the content from the posts. However, if there's in an embedded image or video, like in this post: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/dineshkarna_the-biology-of-courage-what-is-that-ugcPost-6668335979088216064-nQwk/ , I only get the text. Is there any way to also get the media?

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified it a little to suit my code but it works like a charm!. May i ask how did you come by those tags and classes? I couldn't find them as much as I inspected the posts

Comment: My pleasure! You can right-click your browser and check source code when a page is loaded. @F_Bass

Comment: that's what i mean. I checked source code and inspected the elements but i couldn't come by those specific tags and classes you came by

Comment: They're there if you look harder or you can use CTRL+F to search the source code (without the Regular Expressions added and some of the escape sequence like '\') @F_Bass

Comment: I just figured it out. Chrome and Mozilla show different source codes. I was using chrome and that's why i couldn't find that code. I just inspected with mozilla and indeed i see it. Anyways, once more, thank you very much for your help!